# How to sum multiple columns value of DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm doing one project for my institute, and I'm having problem while trying to sum DataGridView columns. I need to calculate Total Amount.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub add()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    dgvStock.Rows.Add()
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("srno").Value = txt_billno.Text
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("itemcode").Value = cmbItemCode.Text
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("itemname").Value = cmbItemName.Text
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("qty").Value = txtQty.Text
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("Rate").Value = txtRate.Text
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("Discount").Value = txtPerDisc.Text
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("PerTax").Value = txtPerVat.Text
    txtAmount.Text = txtRate.Text * txtQty.Text
    txtAmount.Text -= txtPerDisc.Text
    ' txtAmount.Text += txtPerDisc.Text / 100
    dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.RowCount - 1).Cells("Amount").Value = txtAmount.Text
    txtGridAmt.Text = dgvStock.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Amount").Value
    txtdiscRs.Text = dgvStock.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Discount").Value
    txtVatRs.Text = dgvStock.SelectedRows(0).Cells("PerTax").Value
    txtTotAmt.Text = txtGridAmt.Text
End Sub
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Try
        add()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'formclear()
End Sub
```

Here is snapshot of my program it will make my question clearer 
http://postimg.org/image/9ztydl5j1

Comment: Since you called `dgvStock.Rows.Add()` is the last row now empty? Did you debug it and see what it's doing?

Comment: I don't see any sum in your code. What exactly are you trying to sum? What isn't working at the moment?

Comment: Basically i want to sum txtgridamt with txtamount to put in txtTotAmt but while clicking add button as dgv adds one more column so i can update value of txtgridamt it remains same

Comment: your description is confusing.... do you mean adding rows not columns? i dont see you adding columns but new sale = new row right? And you want to see 7000 in the Total Amount Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ways to add or subtract the values does not seem to be correct. Since .Text is a String, not an Integer. Try changing this:

```
txtAmount.Text = txtRate.Text * txtQty.Text
txtAmount.Text -= txtPerDisc.Text
```

To this:

```
txtAmount.Text = CStr(CInt(txtRate.Text) * CInt(txtQty.Text))
txtAmount.Text = CStr(CInt(txtAmount.Text) - CInt(txtPerDisc.Text))
```

--- EDIT ---

Try this instead:

```
Dim NewRow As String() = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
dgvStock.Rows.Add(NewRow)
```

--- EDIT 2 ---

Well:

```
Dim TotalAmount As Integer = 0
For x = 0 To dgvStock.Rows.Count - 1
    TotalAmount += dgvStock.Rows(x).Cells("Amount").Value
Next
```

Before removing:

```
TotalAmount -= dgvStock.Rows(dgvStock.SelectedRows(0)).Cells("Amount").Value
```

Comment: Thanks, btw i already know that and changed to Convert.toInt3 but my main aim is to add value while dgv has got new row

Comment: while i'm adding new row its getting the selected rows value.

Comment: Here is snapshot of my program it will make my question clearer http://postimg.org/image/9ztydl5j1/

Comment: Thanks but i cant get you, because you're adding null row to dgv. it isn't clearing the concept.

Comment: It is adding empty strings in the cells so that it shouldn't copy the text. It isn't null because null in VB is Nothing. object instead of the quotes If you haven't tried it, do so. :)

Comment: Rows.Add() is more null than if you add it with "". :)

Comment: I know that but it isn't solving the problem of sum.

Comment: I want to calculate the value of the dgvStock.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Amount").Value
every time when new row added

Comment: Oh, EDIT #1 was my bad, I thought you wanted a new row with no text in it's cells. I'm currently looking over your main problem.

Comment: Hmm... plus when i remove any cell from dgv it should subtract the amount of that cell

Comment: What do you mean with "Wrong way"?

Comment: ending at loop it should be end at Next its not do loop it for thats why Btw thanks for help

Comment: Ah, I wrote "Loop" instead of "Next". Thanks for noticing. You're welcome for the help. :)